# Control getMultiCapabilities from command line

Tags: webdriver, protractor

I use gulp to run protractor and want one separate task for each browser, Chrome and Firefox. So by running `gulp protractor:chrome` or `gulp protractor:firefox` I would launch different browsers. But I get my capabilities through the `getMultiCapabilities` and it isn't as simple as `--capabilites.browserName chrome` then. This is how my `getMultiCapabilities`-function looks like for Firefox:

```
'use strict';

var FirefoxProfile = require('firefox-profile');
var bbPromise = require('bluebird');

exports.getMultiCapabilities = function () {
    var deferred = bbPromise.defer();

    var firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
    firefoxProfile.setPreference('media.navigator.permission.disabled', true);
    firefoxProfile.encoded(function (encodedProfile) {
        var capabilities = [{
            browserName: 'firefox',
            firefox_profile : encodedProfile
        }];
        deferred.resolve(capabilities);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
};
```

And I want to use this function by passing it in the command line somehow. I tried just requiring the function in the config file and then doing `--getMultiCapabilities firefoxCapabilitiesHelper.getMultiCapabilities`. Didn't work. Also tried to "stringify" the function and wrote everything inside it on the command line. Didn't work either. The arguments are ignored.

Is it even possible to do what I want to achieve?